# mule3 - app zip is deleted when app deploy is failed

Tags: mule, soa, esb

I deployed the hello.zip in mule-standalone-3.4.0/apps, the deploy was failed and when I check the apps folder, the hello.zip got deleted.

It's expected by mule?

And can I set some flag to prevent from deleting?

Comment: are there any file remnants in there?

Comment: I believe this is the issue tracking this https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6831 
The issue is marked as closed, and fixed in 3.1.4, 3.2.4, 3.3.3, 3.4.1 (all EE only) and 3.5.0 M1

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I checked the source code, I found the reason why mule delete the hello.zip:
When deploy succeed, there will be an anchor file generated, when the user want to undeploy the app, s/he can just delete this anchor file, and there is a watcher checks the anchor file, if it does not exist, the app will be undeployed and deleted. However if deploy failed, the anchor file won't be generated, so it get deleted by watcher.